# If $1 > a-b > 0$ then $[a]\geq[b]$

Tags: inequality

what I can do for The case $[a]<[b]$.

I know that $[a]>[b]\Rightarrow [a]\geq [b]+1$

EDIT:

I have realized that the Initial assumption $[a]=[b]$ is false therefore I have changed it to $[a]\geq [b]$

Comment: For clarity, what does $[x]$ mean in this context? I've usually seen this to refer to the rounding function, i.e. rounding $x$ to the nearest integer, but a few counterexamples immediately come to mind in that instance

Comment: $[x]$ is the biggest integer for which we have $\leq x$. Can you give me an counterexample?

Comment: What if $a=1.1$ and $b=0.9$?

Comment: Okay so you're referring to the floor function then @New2Math - so my counterexample would be irrelevant. (Were it rounding and not floor, I was thinking $a=0.6,b=0.4$.) clark's counterexample works for the floor function though.

Comment: @clark I see now that this assumption is false but the assumption $a-b>1\Rightarrow [a]>[b]$ is true right, also If I would have changed the assumption in the question  to $\geq$ then it would be right, right?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking OP

Answer (score 0):

If $a \geq b$ then it immediately follows that $\lfloor a \rfloor \geq \lfloor b\rfloor$. So we don't even need the upper bound.

(All this says is that the floor function is monotone increasing.)